# Critical points: $u = x - 2y + 2z$ if $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 9$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Find the critical points $P$ of $u =x-2y-2z$ given that $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 =9$ and classify if it is maximum, minimum or neither

I've find that $ x = 1 $ or $x=-1$, $y=-z =2$ or $y = -z = -2$ using $ x=^+/_- \sqrt{9 -y^2 - x^2}$. But, it looks like I will have so much work to calculate the determinant of the hessian matrix to decide if it is maximum, minimum or neither for each possible point. Is there a easiest way to do this (I've tried spherical coordinates but doesn't look like a good idea too)? Maybe I am using the hardest path, since my second order derivatives dont have a good form.

Thanks!

Comment: Try : Use $$x=3\cos A, y=3\sin A\cos B,z=3\sin A\sin B$$

Comment: As I said, I've tried this too. But how this make the problem easier?

Comment: @Giovanna, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier

Comment: I will take a look, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

use Cauchy-Schwarz inequality
$$(x^2+y^2+z^2)(1+2^2+2^2)\ge (|x|+2|y|+2|z|)^2\ge (x-2y-2z)^2$$

Answer (score 0):

A similar problem appears here:   [find absolute maximum and minimum with explanation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2843276/find-absolute-maximum-and-minimum-with-explanation/4025174#4025174)

Summarizing the method using a geometric interpretation, the function to be extremized can be considered as the description of a plane.  For $ \ x \  - \  2y \  + \  2z \ = \ 0 \ , $ we have a plane through the origin with normal vector $ \ \langle 1 \ ,  -2 \ , 2 \rangle \ ; $  all planes parallel to this are    $ \ x \  - \  2y \  + \  2z \ = \ d \ . $  There are two such planes that are just tangent to the sphere $ \ x^2 \ + \ y^2 \ + \ z^2 \ = \ 9  \ $ of radius $ \ 3 \ $ centered on the origin.  The distance of these planes from the origin is given by

$$ D \ \ = \ \ 3 \ \ = \ \ \frac{|d \ - \ 0 |}{\sqrt{1^2 \ + \ (-2)^2 \ + \ 2^2}} \ \ = \ \ \frac{|d|}{\sqrt{9}} \ \ , $$

hence, $ \ |d| \ = \ 3 \ · \ 3 \ = \ 9 \ $ .  The maximum and minimum values of  $ \ u \ = \ x \  - \  2y \  + \  2z \  $ are $ \ 9 \ $ and $ \ -9 \ , $ respectively.

Note that the Lagrange equations represented by $ \ \nabla u \ = \ \lambda ·\nabla g \ ,  $ with $ \ g(x,y,z) \ =  \ x^2 \ + \ y^2 \ + \ z^2 \ - \ 9 \ , $ are used to find the locations of points on the sphere where the normal vector to its surface is aligned with the normal vector for the plane (or, the gradient vector of the function $ \ g \ $ is a scalar multiple of the gradient vector of the function $ \ u \ $ ) .  The three equations are

$$ 1 \ \ = \ \ \lambda \ · \ 2x \ \ \ , \ \ \ -2 \ \ = \ \ \lambda \ · \ 2y \ \ \ , \ \ \ 2 \ \ = \ \ \lambda \ · \ 2z $$

$$ \Rightarrow \ \ \ \lambda \ \ = \ \ \frac{1}{2x} \ \ = \ \ \frac{-2}{2y} \ \ = \ \ \frac{2}{2z} \ \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ \ -2x \ \ = \ \ y \ \ = \ \ -z \ \ , $$

which leads us to the above result when inserted into the equation for the sphere.